# "Места, которые ты не хочешь, чтобы я был в них?"

Tags: сложное-предложение

Как грамотно формулировать сложные предложения вроде этого? Прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
Как грамотно формулировать сложные предложения?
```

Вряд ли кто сможет **научить правильно формулировать** предложение, мы можем лишь помочь исправить недочёты в построении конкретных предложений. На один недочёт Вам уже указали. Впрочем, подобная конструкция возможна и без сказуемого — как односоставное назывное или неполное предложение, а вот нанизывание придаточных, затемняющих смысл предложения, называется в лингвистике неэкономной конструкцией. Здесь вполне можно обойтись одним придаточным:

*Места, в которых ты не хочешь меня видеть.*

Особенно бросается в глаза громоздкость конструкции,когда придаточных много:
*Талантливый художник показывает характер своих героев, которые поставлены обстоятельствами в трудные условия, где так четко проявляется их воля к жизни, которой обладает не каждый человек, что становится ясно в конце произведения.*

Может быть ошибочным употребление одного союза (союзного слова) вместо другого, например:

*Мы не может принять на собрании это решение, где не выражено мнение большинства присутствующих.*

Лишним может быть употребление указательных слов в главном предложении:

*Стипендию получают те студенты, которые успешно сдали сессию.*

— вот материал, где разбираются некоторые недочёты. Правильным будет то предложение, где мысль ясна, конструкция легка и понятна, если же есть какие-то неясности, нелогичности — нужно править.

Comment: https://studopedia.ru/17_111091_oshibki-v-postroenii-slozhnopodchinennih-predlozheniy.html

Answer (score 1):

У вас не хватает сказуемого в основной части предложения (получился заголовок).

> Места, в которых моё пребывание для тебя 
>   нежелательно, я всё равно буду посещать.

или:

> Места, в которых моё присутствие для тебя нежелательно, старайся
>   обходить стороной.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Дано содержание: **Места, которые ты не хочешь, чтобы я был в них.**

2) Содержание понятно, **надо подобрать форму**. И сказуемое можно добавить, чтобы предложение получилось.

3) Ну вот так как-то: Э**то те места, в которых тебе не хотелось бы, чтобы я был.**

Например, те места, где ведутся военные действия.

4) Это СПП с последовательным подчинением: придаточное определительное, придаточное изъяснительное.

В то же время структура **нестандартная:** фактически целое придаточное **не хотелось бы, чтобы я был**  является содержанием придаточного определительного предложения.

Такое предложения можно назвать **фразеологизованным**, оно построено по модели, которая применяется только **в разговорной речи.**

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что оформить высказывание, используя  заранее выбранную структуру, **не всегда возможно по стандартным грамматическим образцам.**

Поэтому в нейтральном стиле приходится менять текст и подбирать подходящую форму предложения, например: **Тебе не хотелось бы, чтобы я был в этих местах.**

Comment: Да,  я исправила. А если не звучит, то скажите так: Я не хочу, чтобы ты был в тех местах. Коротко, ясно, и длинные учебные тексты на эту тему не надо писать.